# python using max function on a sub string

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like that:

```
list =  [u'5.0', u'5.1', u'5.2', u'5.3', u'5.4', u'5.5', u'5.6', u'5.7', u'5.8', u'5.9', u'5.10', u'5.11'
```

I am trying to got the highest number after 5. meaning 5.11

I cant use max function here since it will return 5.9

i.e

```
max(list)
```

will result with 5.9 not 5.11

is there a way to run  the max on the second value after 5. so I will get 11?

I was trying to create a new list of the minor versions , and apply max on it
but it presenting only one character after 5. there is probably a better way

```
for minor in list:
    print(minor[2])

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: I'm going to guess because 9 is greater than 1. You'll probably need to create your own comparator function if you need different behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare only the fractional parts (of the corresponding float) by first splitting each string on `'.'` and taking the second part:

```
print(max(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[1])))
# 5.11
```

If the integer parts are not the same, you can compare those first, then use the fractional parts for tie breaking:

```
max(lst, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split('.'))))
```

---

```
>>> lst = ['4.123', '5.053', '5.009']
>>> max(lst, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split('.'))))
'5.053'
```

Comment: but this works only for only 5 number decimals
it might fail when the data is
`list=['4.123','5.009']`

if i am not wrong

Comment: @chakri Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just do so:

```
list =  [u'5.0', u'5.1', u'5.2', u'5.3', u'5.4', u'5.5', u'5.6', u'5.7', u'5.8', u'5.9', u'5.10', u'5.11']
minor_list = [int(i[2:]) for i in list]
print("5." + str(max(minor_list))) # should work

for item in list:
    print(item[2:])
```

See https://repl.it/MmK9

Answer (score 0):

```
print(max(list,key=lambda x:int(x.replace(".",""))))
```

Comment: It's usually helpful to explain code rather than just pasting and posting.